# Remove selected color from image (grayscale graphic)

Tags: photoshop

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i36po.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/beM5a.png)
Hi guys! I have the following task: I must paint the black and white house, leaning to a result as the colored one.
I figured out, there must be a way to somehow "remove" the white color, so there is only the black outlines left. From there I will make an underlayer and will insert color/materials etc.

The hard part and the essential in my question is: The black outlines are ranging from true black to very light grey. Is there a way I can somehow delete all white (0,0,0) pixels and for the others: the more "black" they have, the more opacity they get. So a grey pixel with a value around (126,126,126) will be left, but with a 50% opacity.

Comment: what you actually want? didn't understand..

Answer (score 0):

have you tried, copying the same image on top of the original image, change the copied image blending mode to overlay,  use the select tool on the white area, and then click the select tab on top menu, from that tab click select similar,so you have all the white area selected, then select the original layer, and then erase, you can also erase delete the copied image. Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can,

Open "Select" menu and choose "Color Range", it will open a dialog box, inside that box you can choose from the drop down at the top if you want to select Reds, Yellows, Greens, etc. or you can select Sampled Colors with the eyedropper tool, so you can select the white color from anywhere at the image then you can handle the color range sensitivity from the slide bar called Fuzziness, the lower number is the lower range of white color and vise versa :)

Answer (score 0):

As Ahmed Alaa said, use the "Color Range" tool, but for coloring in black and white images, see if my Youtube tutorial can help.

-https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4My4dVU5iUE

P.S. Sorry this post is bad, i'm new-ish.